# Как объединить два exe файла в один

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio

Имеется программа в виде одного исполняемого файла, доступа к ее исходникам нет. Также есть вспомогательная программа, которая, исходя из особенностей операционной системы, запускает основную программу с определенными параметрами(к ее исходникам доступ есть). Сейчас вспомогательная программа принимает путь до основной и запускает ее. Как объединить обе программы в один exe файл?

Comment: SFX-архив определенно сможет их "объединить"...

Comment: Конечно это так, но нужно чтобы результатом объединения стал exe файл

Comment: так sfx архив и даст exe файл

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Проще всего добавить этот exe в ресурсы Вашей программы и загружать его через `FindResource/LoadResource/LockResource`.

Похожий вопрос с аналогичным решением: [how to use a resource file (txt - tab delimited) as a data source for win32 application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1994576/how-to-use-a-resource-file-txt-tab-delimited-as-a-data-source-for-win32-appl) (тут в ответах масса вариаций на одну и ту же тему)

---

Кроме того, этот вариант позволяет модифицировать такой ресурс без пересборки Вашего приложения (например, когда появляется новая версия).

Пример из msdn: [Updating Resources](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648008(v=vs.85).aspx#_win32_Updating_Resources)

Answer (score 3):

Через задницу, но...

Записываете файл как массив байт в основную программу. Когда нужно - сбрасываете ее в файл, запускаете, потом удаляете.